# Database does not exist - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have created a database using Entity Framework.

I had to change something and I have selected "Update Database from Model".
I have generated SQL and when I press "Execute" I get this error:

> Database 'SiteBis2015' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

Here is the code:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;
GO

USE [SiteBis2015];
GO

IF SCHEMA_ID(N'dbo') IS NULL EXECUTE(N'CREATE SCHEMA [dbo]');
GO
```

What can I do? Thanks

Comment: How you are creating the database? Can you show?

Comment: From edmx I select one table and I add Scalar Property. Then Generate Database from Model